# Own file export option only prints the first character (Trac plugin)

Tags: python, plugins, trac

I wrote a Trac plugin that adds another export option to the custom query module. The plugin itself works so far, but I've run into the problem that, when I click on the link in the *Download in other formats* section, only the first character is shown printed out.

For testing purposes I let the `convert_content` method of the `IContentConverter` return a simple string.

But whatever the string's content is, only the first character is printed.

Example:

> If the string says `test`, clicking the link opens a new tab with only the 
>   letter `t`.
>
> If the string says `asdf`, clicking the link opens a new tab with only the letter `a`.

Does Trac somehow expect me to return all of the characters one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I looked up the implementation for the csv export in the Trac source and realised that I need to return a tuple containing the actual result and the mimetype.

This is the section from the csv export:

```
return iterate(), '%s;charset=utf-8' % mimetype
```

I don't know why it didn't throw an error, though. Maybe it is a bug in Trac that it prints the first letter of the returned string when no mimetype is given.